# HTML page duplicates itself when I type in search bar

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to make a simple search bar. The search bar sends  data through JQuery to PHP (which performs the search). The data is sent back to HTML through the callback function. The search functionality is working as it should. However,every time I type in the search input, the whole page duplicates itself. I don't know why it does so. The data is being fetched from a MySQL database.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connection/connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['search_term'])){
    $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect,htmlentities($_POST['search_term']));

if(!empty($search_term)){
    $sql_search = "SELECT first FROM students_register WHERE first LIKE '%$search_term%' ";
    $result_search = $db_connect->query($sql_search);
    $result_count = $result_search->num_rows;

    $suffix = ($result_count != 1) ? 's' : '';
    echo "<p>Your search for <strong>" .$search_term. " </strong>has returned <strong>".$result_count."</strong> result" .$suffix. "</p>";

    while($results_row = $result_search->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<p><strong>".$results_row['first']."</strong></p>";
        }
    }

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Search: <input id="search" name="search" placeholder="search">
    <span id="search_display"></span>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search_term = $(this).val(); 

        $.post('test2.php', {search_term : search_term}, function(result){
            $("#search_display").html(result);

        });

    });
    </script>
</html>
```

**``**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here I have question is `test2.php` and your html page also same page?

try with two pages,

```
<?php // test2.php
  session_start();
  include("connection/connection.php");
 if(isset($_POST['search_term'])){
      $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect,htmlentities($_POST['search_term']));

   if(!empty($search_term)){
     $sql_search = "SELECT first FROM students_register WHERE first LIKE '%$search_term%' ";
     $result_search = $db_connect->query($sql_search);
     $result_count = $result_search->num_rows;

     $suffix = ($result_count != 1) ? 's' : '';
     echo "<p>Your search for <strong>" .$search_term. " </strong>has returned <strong>".$result_count."</strong> result" .$suffix. "</p>";

    while($results_row = $result_search->fetch_assoc()){
       echo "<p><strong>".$results_row['first']."</strong></p>";
    }
  }

}
```

?>
And the Html contains another page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
  <title>Index.html</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>


 </head>
   <body>
 Search: <input id="search" name="search" placeholder="search">
   <span id="search_display"></span>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
       $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search_term = $(this).val(); 
        $.post('test2.php', {search_term : search_term}, function(result){
            $("#search_display").html(result);

        });

    });
    </script>

</html>
```

The reason is, you are requesting the data from the test2.php, the test2.php has contain also with the html code, So that only it reappear again and again.  please try this let me know the results.

Comment: Sidenote: `mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect,htmlentities` that can be narrowed down to simply using a prepared statement. `htmlentities()` doesn't do anything to help against an sql injection, it's for viewing only.

Comment: This has worked like a charm. I separated the PHP and HTML and it worked out just fine. Thanks alot

Comment: Cool... keep in mind while using ajax, make php code on another file, and after `echo` the result and use `die` for finish the execute

Comment: Please add comment, for down voting please

Comment: I have clicked the place it says 'click here if this answer was helpful' Is that it?

Comment: Yes, click up arrow `This answer is helpful` but i dont know why it shows -1

Comment: Yeah, its showing -1, donno why. Tried changing it  and it goes back to -1

Comment: ok if you click up arrow it will show orange color is on that color? @nzioker

Comment: No, it is grey in color

Comment: So you clicked down arrow please click up arrow @nzioker